# How to merge all data frames of Global Environment with characters in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, bind

I have 48 data frames in my global environment, and I would like to merge them accordingly to column 1 (of each one). All data frames have only 1 column and are in this style:

`df1 <- data.frame("Genes" = c("EGF", "FGF", "IGF"))`

`df2 <- data.frame("Genes" = c("Myo6", "NRP2", "P23"))`

I tried converting them into a list, but then, what I wanted to merge was level 2 of each one so it turned complicated.

Expected final result:

`df3 <- data.frame("Genes" = c("EGF", "FGF", "IGF", "Myo6", "NRP2", "P23"))`

If anyone could help, it'd be wonderful
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, is one option with `mget` to load all the object with names that start with 'ZEB' followed by digits into a `list`, `unlist` the `list` and create the `data.frame`

```
out <- data.frame(Genes = unlist(unname(mget(ls(pattern = '^ZEB[1-2]')))))
```

Comment: The problem, then, is that every data frame has a different name (not like just differing on numbers like df1, df2, df3...)

Comment: @NunoRamalho is there any patterns?

Comment: @NunoRamalho updated the post

Comment: for example, "ZEB1_common_30genes_all_datasets", "ZEB1_MARY_JOHN_positive", "ZEB2_common_60genes_all_datasets", and so on... the pattern is the "ZEB1" or "ZEB2", always.

Comment: @NunoRamalho if you check my update that should cover

Comment: This error appears ---- Error in names(i1)[i1] : invalid subscript type 'list'
while runing the ```lst1 <- mget(names(i1)[i1])````code

Comment: @NunoRamalho I also changed the initial code.  Please check that

Comment: Thank you! You saved me